# Getting a frame error when trying to link features in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame showing 6 moving particles and their positions in every frame. I want to make that data into trajectories but I can't because of an error when using the function tp.link(). Here's the scatterplot of the particles moving.

And here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
vidcapture = cv2.VideoCapture('FJ_motilecells.avi') #create variable and attribute it to the video
def getFrame(sec):   #
    vidcapture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)
    hasFrames,image = vidcapture.read()
    if hasFrames:
        cv2.imwrite("images"+str(count)+".jpg", image)  #converts the frame into a jpg
    return hasFrames
sec = 0
frameRate = 1/15 #set the framarate to 15 per second
count=1
success = getFrame(sec)
while success:
    count = count + 1
    sec = sec + frameRate
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    success = getFrame(sec)
images = pims.open('./*.jpg') #use pims to read jpg files
images[4]
    



 #make the 4th frame gray scale
gray = rgb2gray(images[4])
binary = gray < 0.3  #set the threshold
plt.imshow(binary)




#part 3.2

thresh = 0.3  #set up a threshold to exclude noise

from skimage import measure #import function to measure properties of highlighted image


frames = 0 
df2= pd.DataFrame([])
for image in images:
    gs1 = rgb2gray(image)
    binary1 = gs1< thresh
    labels = measure.label(binary1) #label each dot on the image
    props = measure.regionprops(labels) # set a variable for the regionprop of each label
    cent=[] #create a blank list for the centroids
    frames = frames + 1
    for x in props:
        centroid = [x.centroid]
        x_pos = centroid[0][0]
        y_pos = centroid[0][1]
        data = [x.label,x.area,x_pos, y_pos, x.major_axis_length,x.minor_axis_length,frames]  #use the .area/label/centroid functions from skimage
        cent.append(data) #add the data pieces to the blank list
        cell_data = DataFrame(cent, columns=['label','mass','x', 'y','Centroid', 'Majoraxis', 'Minoraxis'])  #create a dataframe
    df2 = df2.append(cell_data)
df3 = df2[~(df2['mass'] <= 200)]  # this is the mass filter to remove noise
```

edit: sorry, I forgot to include the error, here it is;

```
``KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, 
key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'frame'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-232-23c1d6e1e345> in <module>
----> 1 track = tp.link(df3,5)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\trackpy\linking\linking.py in link(f, 
search_range, pos_columns, t_column, **kwargs)
    183     f = f.copy()
    184     # coerce t_column to integer type
--> 185     if not np.issubdtype(f[t_column].dtype, np.integer):
    186         f[t_column] = f[t_column].astype(np.integer)
    187     # sort on the t_column

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, 
key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, 
key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'frame'``
```

Comment: Please show the error and more than one line of code.

Comment: It's included now.

Comment: More code, please!

Comment: It included now, sorry